# Wordpress Admin ajax is getting CORS error when on www

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

My WP site works on both www and non-www, but I have a form that makes a call to admin-ajax.php and when I'm on www I get a CORS error.

The form is using `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>` to get the admin ajax url but it always gets it without www so I get this error:
[image]

Is there a way to get the admin url with www or without www depending on whether the user is on www or non www or can I change admin-ajax to accept for www or non www? or do I just need to change the js to construct the admin url without using the WP php functions?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variable and compare it to admin_url. Then add or delete the www subdomain using this value **str_replace** function to avoid getting the error where the function is running.